# Javaのhost設定

Tags: java

### 前提

現在 Web サイト上から画像を保存するアプリを制作しています。

---

### 発生している問題

以下のコードをお借りしましたが

> java.net.UnknownHostException: sampledomail.com

とエラーがでており調べたら host 設定の不備のようだったのですがどこでどのように設定をすればよろしいのでしょうか。

---

### 該当のソースコード

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class GetFile {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new GetFile();
    }
    public GetFile() {
        try {
            URI uri = new URI("http://sampledomail.com/sample.jpg");
            URL url = uri.toURL();
            URLConnection urlcon = url.openConnection();
            InputStream fileIS = urlcon.getInputStream();
            File saveFile = new File("a.jpg");
            FileOutputStream fileOS = new FileOutputStream(saveFile);
            int c;
            while ((c = fileIS.read()) != -1) fileOS.write((byte) c);
            fileOS.close();
            fileIS.close();

        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

初心者でうまく説明できていない部分も多々あると思いますが宜しくお願いいたします。

Comment: `http://sampledomail.com/` この部分は正しいホスト名(アドレス）ですか？

Comment: 古いサイトでリンク切れしてました（汗）先ほど違うリンクを試したら動きました。
しょうもない質問してしまい失礼いたしました。

Answer (score 1):

`http://sampledomail.com/`がリンク切れしていることが原因でした。違うリンクを試したら動きました。

---

<sup>この投稿は @ふなっしー さんの[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/10547/java%e3%81%aehost%e8%a8%ad%e5%ae%9a#comment9546_10547)などを元に編集し、[コミュニティWiki](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1583)として投稿しました。</sup>